# Count(distinct) over (partition by) sql server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table like the below

| class_no | student_id | subject_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 636 | Physics |
| 1 | 636 | Chemistry |
| 1 | 637 | Maths |
| 1 | 638 | German |
| 1 | 639 | Physics |

```
Create table #T_Test(
     class_no int
     ,student_id int
     ,subject_name nvarchar(25)
);
Insert into #T_Test ([class_no],[student_id],[subject_name]) values
(1,636,'Physics'),
(1,636,'Chemistry'),
(1,637,'Maths'),
(1,638,'German'),
(1,639,'Physics')
```

I want to get the count of distinct student_id, also count grouped_by subject_names

| class_no | subject_name | total_subjects | total_students |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Physics | 2 | 4 |
| 1 | Chemistry | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | Maths | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | German | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | Physics | 1 | 4 |

Below is what I have done so far, how can I get the distinct count(student_id) included in the resultset

```
SELECT  DISTINCT t.class_no
        ,t.subject_name
        ,count(*) total_subject
FROM        #T_Test t
WHERE       t.class_no = 1
GROUP BY    t.class_no,subject_name
```

Comment: No need to do `SELECT DISTINCT` here, the `GROUP BY` returns no duplicates.

Comment: All looks ok , what is that you need ? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=95d31393015b63275137b914e8bfe955

Comment: @VBoka I want to include the count (distinct (student_id)) in the resultset

Comment: Hi @winny, if my query from the link is not good then the query from the answer below is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You are looking for this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    t.class_no,
    t.subject_name,
    total_subjects = Count(t.subject_name) OVER(Partition By t.class_no, t.subject_name),
    total_students = (SELECT COUNT(Distinct [student_id]) FROM #T_Test)
FROM    #T_Test t
WHERE   t.class_no = 1
```

Comment: Thanks @Md. Tarikul Islam Soikot it does work for me by making a tiny modification but I am just worried about the performance                                                                          
     SELECT DISTINCT 
    t.class_no,
    t.subject_name,
    total_subjects = Count(t.subject_name) OVER(Partition By t.class_no, t.subject_name),
    total_students = (SELECT COUNT(Distinct [student_id]) FROM #T_Test where t.class_no = 1)
FROM    #T_Test t
WHERE   t.class_no = 1

Comment: I have just run this query over 500000 rows. and it takes only 1 sec. @winny

Answer (score 1):

By using this little `dense_rank` trick, it's possible to get your aggregate for subjects and the distinct student count without requiring to hit the table multiple times:

```
with s as (
    select class_no, subject_name,
    Dense_Rank() over (partition by class_no order by student_id) + 
    Dense_rank() over (partition by class_no order by student_id desc) - 1 Students
    from #T_Test
)
select class_no, subject_name,  
  Count(*) Total_Subjects, 
  Max(students) Total_Students
from s
group by class_no, subject_name
```